# jQuery Ajax PUT with parameters

Tags: jquery

It seems that using jQuery Ajax POST will pass parameters, but PUT will 
not. I looked at the current jQuery code and PUT and DELETE are not there. I looked at 1.4.2 jQuery and PUT and DELETE are there.

What is the workaround for passing parameters with a PUT request using the current version of jQuery?

Answer (score 96):

Can you provide an example, because put should work fine as well?

Documentation -

The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"); the default is "GET". *Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.*

Have the example in fiddle and the form parameters are passed fine (as it is put it will not be appended to `url`) -

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/echo/html/',
  type: 'PUT',
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/udsXH/) tested from jQuery 1.3.2 onwards on Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried getting parameters on server side? I use getParameter() in doPut() and params are not passed

Comment: i tried using HttpRequest and same result, so it's not jquery fault, but why latest Chrome doesn't pass PUT params?

Comment: if i append params to url it works, but it's just not right way to pass params

Comment: So Jayendra, thanks, are you saying servlet engine (i am using Tomcat)  will not get params for PUT request and I should parse it myself from the input stream?

Comment: Demo link is broken

Answer (score 38):

You can use the PUT method and pass data that will be included in the body of the request:

```
let data = {"key":"value"}

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://example.com/api',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // access in body
}).done(function () {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
}).fail(function (msg) {
    console.log('FAIL');
}).always(function (msg) {
    console.log('ALWAYS');
});
```

Comment: The line with the comment `// access in body` - how can that data be accessed?  In PHP when I try this and do some echoing both the $_GET and $_POST superglobals are empty arrays.

Comment: It seems that adding `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` to the PHP script allows the data to be accessed.

Comment: NOTE: jQuery 1.9+ added `method` which is used instead of `type` so if you're coming here wondering why the docs aren't working, you might be running an older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

For others who wind up here like I did, you can use AJAX to do a PUT with parameters, but they are sent as the body, not as query strings.

Answer (score -9):

Use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'feed/4', type: 'POST', data: "_METHOD=PUT&accessToken=63ce0fde", success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Always remember to use `_METHOD=PUT`.

Comment: I would generally advise against parsing the data as a string as this prevents the app been dynamic and is harder to read than a simple object array. Additionally you can use `type: 'PUT'` instead of putting it in the data.