# Send an ajax put request with multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, put

I want to send a put request to my API with multiple files and a JSON object. I don't want it to be post, I don't mind using JQuery AJAX call or any JavaScript AJAX call. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax PUT with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032938/jquery-ajax-put-with-parameters)

Comment: No i need to send files, multiple files...