# CodeIgniter REST server Only Get is possible as method

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter REST server by Phil Sturgeon found [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) and I am struggling to direct towards any other method other than GET. I have modified the code below:

```
function _ajaxEvent($element) {
    $.ajax({
            // URL from the link that was 'clicked' on

        url: $element.attr('href'),
        method: 'PUT'
        })
        .done(_ajaxDone)
        .fail(_ajaxFail);
}
```

and by theory this should be a PUT request and according to this particular implementation it should call a method similar to users_put, however neither am I able to call the users_put but the network monitor also displays as a GET.

I would really appreciate some advice on this. Looks like I've missed something.

Comment: It is type not method, you should write type: 'PUT'

Comment: This question has nothing to do with codeigniter or php. This question is how to make an ajax call. See duplicate question with answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032938/jquery-ajax-put-with-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax PUT with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032938/jquery-ajax-put-with-parameters)