# How to real time update a form in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Recently I found myself having to create a page that users can freely fill out, but I am struggling to understand how to make the page capable of saving changes in **real-time**.

The idea is that every time the user selects an option from a dropdown or types characters in a textarea, the state (the change) should be saved without the need to click a button or anything else.

I have already tried the following code, but I get a 419 error from the console, and the data is not being saved to the database.

**HTML**:

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
    <tr>
        <th>@lang('quickadmin.inspections.fields.inspection-date')</th>
        <td field-key='inspection_date'>
            {!! Form::text('inspection_date', old('inspection_date'), [
                'class' => 'form-control date',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'id' => 'inspection_date',
            ]) !!}
        </td>

    <tr>
        <th>@lang('quickadmin.inspections.fields.execution-date')</th>
        <td field-key='execution_date'>
            {!! Form::text('execution_date', old('execution_date'), [
                'class' => 'form-control date',
                'id' => 'execution_date',
                'placeholder' => '',
            ]) !!}
        </td>

        <th>@lang('quickadmin.inspections.fields.execution-hour')</th>
        <td field-key='execution_time'>
            {!! Form::text('execution_time', old('execution_time'), [
                'class' => 'form-control timepicker',
                'id' => 'execution_time',
                'placeholder' => '',
            ]) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Veicolo</th>
        <td field-key='vehicles' colspan="3">
            {!! Form::select('vehicles[]', $vehicles, old('vehicles'), ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'id' => 'selectall-methods' ]) !!}
            <p class="help-block"></p>
            @if($errors->has('vehicles'))
                <p class="help-block">
                    {{ $errors->first('vehicles') }}
                </p>
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th>Trasferta [minuti]</th>
        <td field-key='trip_time' colspan="3">
            {!! Form::text('trip_time', old('trip_time'), [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id' => 'trip_time',
                'placeholder' => 'Esempio: 28 [min]',
            ]) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Descrizione dell'intervento</th>
        <td field-key='inspection_note' colspan="3">
            @if ($inspection->inspection_note != null)
                <textarea id="desc" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;resize: none;" rows="5" maxlength="80">{{ $inspection->inspection_note }}</textarea>
            @else
                <textarea id="desc" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;resize: none;" rows="5" placeholder="Descrizione intervento"
                 maxlength="80"></textarea>
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script>
    // This code will update the database when the user changes the value of a field
    $(function() {
        $('.form-control').on('change', function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::token() }}"
            }
        });

            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/new_inspections/update/' + {{ $inspection->id }},
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    inspection_date: $('#inspection_date').val(),
                    inspection_time: $('#inspection_time').val(),
                    inspection_state: $('#inspection_state').find("option:selected").attr('value'),
                    user_code: $('#user_code').find("option:selected").attr('value'),
                    inspection_note: $('textarea#desc').val(),
                    trip_time: $('#trip_time').val(),
                    execution_date: $('#execution_date').val(),
                    execution_hour: $('#execution_time').val(),
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        console.log('Product updated successfully!');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error updating product!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller update** (The code can't even enter it):

```
public function update(UpdateNewInspectionRequest $request, $id)
{
    $inspection = NewInspection::findOrFail($id);
    $inspection->extra_vehicles()->sync(array_filter((array)$request->input('extra_vehicles')));
    $inspection->update($request->all());
    $inspection->save();

    return back();
}
```

I don't know if it could be important, but the feature I'm trying to implement was present in an old version of the website on a different host. About 6 months ago, we changed hosts and migrated the site. It's possible that the issue lies in the change of a reference?

Comment: HTTP status code 419 is what laravel uses when the CSRF token is not valid.

Comment: 419 indicate that your X-CSRF-TOKEN isn't valid, try it with 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}" if you don't use csrf token in your form

Comment: Under "saving changes in real-time", do you mean AJAX save without clicking the 'Save' button?

Comment: @Gireada: Thank you for the suggestion, but I have already tried it and the result is always the same (419).

Comment: @Tpojka: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Then you should implement it in JS code. Check how to invoke events. Do you use some JS framework or library like Vue, React, jQuery?

Comment: @Tpojka: I'm using jQuery

Comment: @Drakdy change the authorization value in UpdateNewInspectionRequest

Comment: @Gireada: More open than this is impossible:
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

Comment: You should set event listener on exact elements, not on wrapping div. Find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153047/detect-changed-input-text-box) some ideas.

Comment: @Tpojka: Actually, that's the only part of the code that works without issues, as I can retrieve the form's value and display it in the console. The real problem is that I'm unable to send the data to the controller (NewInspectionController). With the PUT and PATCH methods, I get error 405, while with the POST method, I get error 419.

Comment: Have you tried to use CSRF token like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)? Also, can you show how is defined that route in route file (edit question with it)? [PUT within AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032938/jquery-ajax-put-with-parameters) tested?

Comment: @Tpojka: Yes I tried that code as well with no result.
web.php: Route::PUT('new_inspections/update/{id}', ['uses' => 'Admin\NewInspectionsController@update', 'as' => 'new_inspections.update']);

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do real-time updates, then this surely sounds like you need an asynchronous JavaScript solution. Specifically for that, there is the Laravel Package [Inertia](https://inertiajs.com) which allows to build asynchronous JavaScript forms. Specifically see [this page of the documentation](https://inertiajs.com/forms).

Alternatively, there is also [Livewire](https://livewire.laravel.com/) which allows you do to the same thing using PHP.

Comment: I have tested both options (that's why it took me so long to reply, sorry), but I am unable to download Inertia due to an error, while Livewire would require a code rewrite that could potentially cause more issues than before, and I haven't been able to test the feature yet, but I'm still experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my absence from this project, but I recently returned to work on this page, and (perhaps thanks to this period on another project), I managed to identify the problem and solve it.

I am updating this post with the aim of helping, whenever possible, those who may have found themselves in the same situation.

Apparently, the URL I assigned within the JavaScript code was incorrect due to the structure of the website.

Below, you can see the correct code:

```
function updateData() {
                trip_time = $('#trip_time').val();
                id = {{ $inspection->id }};
                state = $('#enum_inspection_state').find("option:selected").attr('value');
                inspection_note = $('#desc').val();
                user_code = $('#user_code').find("option:selected").attr('value');
                datetime_inspection = $('#datetime_inspection').val();
                datetime_execution = $('#datetime_execution').val();
                vehicles = $('#vehicles').val();
                recontact = $('#recontact').val();
                offer_response = $('#offer_response').val();
                offer_rejected_details = $('#offer_rejected_details').val();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url("admin/new_inspections/saveData") }}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        state: state,
                        user_code: user_code,
                        datetime_inspection: datetime_inspection,
                        datetime_execution: datetime_execution,
                        trip_time: trip_time,
                        inspection_note: inspection_note,
                        vehicles: vehicles,
                        offer_response: offer_response,
                        offer_rejected_details: offer_rejected_details,
                        rejected_other: rejected_other,
                        rejected_cost: rejected_cost,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('Saved successfully.');
                        if(!($('#enum_inspection_state').find("option:selected").attr('value') == 'Da fare')){
if(document.getElementById('enum_inspection_state').disabled == false){
                                location.reload();
                            }
document.getElementById('enum_inspection_state').disabled = true;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error('Errore nella richiesta AJAX:', textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Thanks to everyone for the support, and I apologize if the error was such a triviality.